# Space lines vertically

Tags: font-size, css

I have three lines of text I want to space evenly near a box of `height=100px;` (an image actually)

Is there anything I can do that will do this automagically? Or do I have to calculate line heights and change the `padding`s `margin`s `line height`s and `font sizes`?

Comment: Can you post some of your workaround

Comment: include your html and css to easily help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution involves the height of the element containing your lines of text.  Since your block is 100px, you want the block containing the text to also be 100px.  It could also be three separate blocks that add up to 100px.

Here are two separate solutions that both work.

HTML:

```
<div class="box1">box1</div>
<p class="p1">This is line 1.<br>
This is line 2.<br>
This is line 3.</p>
```

CSS:

```
.p1 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 33px;
  background-color: silver;
}
.box1 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  float: left;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="box2">box2</div>
<p class="p2">This is line 1.</p>
<p class="p3">This is line 2.</p>
<p class="p4">This is line 3.</p>
```

CSS:

```
.p2, .p3, .p4 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 33.3px;
  line-height: 33.3px;
  background-color: silver;
}

.box2 {
  background-color: green;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
}
```

[Demo at CodePen](http://codepen.io/Ghodmode/pen/IxGsn)

In the second solution (separate blocks), you can leave out the line-height and the first line of text will align with the top of the box with the other lines spaced evenly below it.

Answer (score 1):

You could apply a `line-height` that is one-third the image `height`.

```
img {
    height: 100px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.text {
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 300px;
    line-height: 33.33px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/myajouri/Nk5Hj/